# Vue data target in components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

WHen I add a data-target to my component it stops showing the elements. I tried harcoding an ID but no matter what I do it dosent shown with data-target:

```
Vue.component('kk-directory', {
props: ['directoryData'],
template: '<li>'+
                '<input type="checkbox" v-model="directoryData.Selected" v-on:change=" $root.selectedChange(directoryData)" v-show="!directoryData.Migrate">'+
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" ng-click="selectChilds(directoryData)"></span>'+
                '<a href="#" v-on:click="!directoryData.Loaded && $root.add(directoryData)" data-toggle="collapse" **:data-target="#'+'{{directoryData.DirectoryId}}">**'+
                    '<b>{{ directoryData.Name }}:</b>'+
                    '<span>files({{ directoryData.FileCountCurrentFolder }})</span>, files total (<span ng-class="{\'danger\': directoryData.FileCountTotal > 5000}">{{ directoryData.FileCountTotal }}</span>), <span>GB ({{ directoryData.SizeGB }})</span>'+
                '</a>'+
                '<ul id="{{directoryData.DirectoryId}}" class="">'+
                     '<li v-for="dir in directoryData.Childs">'+
                        '<kk-directory :directory-data="dir"></kk-directory >'+
                    '</li>'+
                '</ul>'+    
            '</li>'
```

})

Is in not possible to bind a data-target in components?

Comment: Your code has too much problem! What is `**`, and your closing `'` and `"`

Comment: you might want to consider template strings instead i.e. `\``

Comment: Sry the ** is stackoverflow bold. So ignore them. I think its closed correctly with the ' ?

Comment: I am new to Vue, but isent this a s string template?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Following worked:

```
'<a href="#" v-on:click="!directoryData.Loaded && $root.add(directoryData)" data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="\'#d\'+directoryData.DirectoryId">'
```

Comment: I can see its not buityfull, considering to read up on single file components to see if thats more elegant.